# Jenkins error script.sh in otput with ansicolor

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I´m trying to use ansicolor to colorize sh command in jenkins. thing is that I´m having following error when I execute it.(just to mention git IS installed as pulling step it´s done successfully) This is script I´m using for sh command:

```
node {

    stage ('Pulling code from Bitbucket') {


        git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxxx/test.git'


                wrap([$class: 'AnsiColorBuildWrapper', 'colorMapName': 'xterm']) {

               sh ("""\033[35mgit branch\033[0m""")

               }

               }

          }
```

[image]

If I put `sh 'git branch'` command without ansicolor it works ok:

```
[workspace] Running shell script
+ git branch
* master
```

I also tried using returnStdout to check if worked to pass sh command output like this:

```
node {

    stage ('Pulling code from Bitbucket') {


        git branch: 'master',
                credentialsId: '2bbc73c4-254e-45bd-85f4-6a169699310c',
                url: 'git@bitbucket.org:xxxxx/test.git'



          script {
               //VAR = sh("""returnStdout: true, script: 'git branch """)

               //println "${VAR}"

               }
```

And I´m also getting same error as ansicolor like this.

[image]

What can this be related to? thanks.-

(EDITED)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `sh` syntax is incorrect. The correct syntax is:

```
sh returnStdout: true, script: 'git branch'
```

Comment: Yes I check that and stdout is ok now, but still getting not found for ansicolo. Is it possible to colorize sh commands? or just Echo and println. How can I do this? println and echo "something" is working fine but a regular sh command just like "git status" or "git branch" it get colorized but then I´m getting: durable-d61b2999/script.sh: git: not found

Comment: is installed if not code wouldn´t have been pulled in first place check entire code. If I do git status or git branch without ansicolor , it works. If I do it with asnicolor it throws that error that i´m showwing

Comment: The master has it installed. It's not installed on slave.

Comment: chek last image. If I use color in common println it shows output. But if I do it on sh command not. that´s the issue. As you can see git is installed and working ok